# Metabolic Stasis and Longevity

Tags: biology

Suppose a creature or human(oid) regularly underwent a metabolic stasis. Would this contribute to a longer overall lifespan? Or are there other factors at play here?

...

I'm looking at using this in a situation where the stasis is magically induced (Gargoyles), but I was curious as to what the effects might look like in a more natural setting.

Comment: Voluntarily natural ("I think I want to go into stasis for a few decades"), or *environmentally induced* stasis (similar but more extreme than bears' torpor)?

Comment: Please tell us more. Are we talking about stone-age people where predators are a real concern? What about war? What about disease? You are vulnerable if you are in "stasis" which might contribute to why this isn't something that exists. Most people in history would have died. Do all of these humanoids undergo stasis or only a couple of them? Have you considered that people sleep? We lack information

Comment: From the other answers it seems like it doesn't really extend the life beyond the additional added stasis, but I think if, for a story, you tweaked the mechanism of the sleep, you could justify a longer life.  Perhaps it's more like a rejuvenation that requires "sleep" to undergo.  You come out with new cells and another decade or so to live before sleeping again.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nature, hibernation, aestivation and torpor only extends lifespan in that if the creature **didn't** hibernate/aestivate/enter torpor, it would very likely die. These periods of 'stasis' are a method of avoiding harsh environmental times - such as bitter cold winters or prolonged dry seasons. (An alternative strategy is to migrate away to somewhere better). Biological 'stasis' is all about saving resources in time of need. Brown bears which live in warm climates (e.g. Spain) do not hibernate in winter, whilst the same species of bear in cold climates (e.g. Canada) do. There's enough food available in a Spanish winter for the bears not to bother.

You build up your fat reserves in the good times, then retreat into a **safe, secret place** and live off those fat reserves while you sleep. The place has to be safe and secret, because the creatures which don't hibernate or migrate away are desperately hungry and your sleeping body looks like a nice, easy meal. Also, if you are in a burrow or cave, the temperature won't be as cold as the outside world, so your fat reserves will last longer than if you went to sleep outdoors.

A longer or harsher than average winter/dry season will kill hibernating creatures - their reserves will run out before the spring/wet season food sources become available. They'll die in their sleep or wake up and then starve. However, if your magical stasis totally 'freezes' the creature so it's metabolism is not expending energy and using resources at all, then there is no risk of this happening.

Answer (score 2):

First - To Secespitus: If I had wanted this formatted differently, I would have done so.  Leave it Alone, the answer was exactly how I intended it.

Points that may answer your question, 'Hibernation' ( think Bears) is a naturally occurring process that slows metabolic rate , and induces 'torpor', a vastly reduced awareness and activity level. The underlying feature is that it is needed to sustain an animal over a winter, drought or other temporary, yet predictable span of time, usually seasonal. Hibernation doesn't suspend metabolism, just reduces it to a very low rate. A bear that hibernates will likely have about the same life expectancy as one that doesn't - provided the elements don't interfere. "Stasis" is largely the work of Science Fiction, and despite its frequent treatments in film like "Alien" or "Avatar", we don't have means to truly apply 'stasis' to a complex organism with much hope of reviving it. Your question implies " Magic", I assume more Gandalf than Houdini. A true 'stasis' - whether scientific (Alien freezers) or Magic (?) would extend the year that the organism would hope to see, but not modify whatever pre-programmed genetic life expectancy. In short, no. You could be around to see the year 2525, but you'd still die of old age at a (subjective) 75-90 years old. - Just my two cents...

Comment: In the 1968 *Planet of the Apes*, the woman's stasis chamber broke, causing her to die of old age, whereas the other three characters lived.

Comment: understood, stasis broken, fatality ensued;   counterpoint to the *hibernating* astronauts in "2001: A Space Odyssey" who died of anoxia and decompression when HAL9000 decompressed the 'Discovery'.

Comment: Of course, neither of these situations are "natural settings".  :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Alaskan Wood Frog](http://voices.nationalgeographic.com/2013/08/21/how-the-alaska-wood-frog-survives-being-frozen/). It spends much of the year effectively frozen solid (65% solid anyway).

Whether or not this extends its ultimate lifespan I've yet to discover however metabolic processes do effectively completely halt during a freeze period.

Effectively lifespan on the other hand? Have you actually lived longer if you lived your 3 score and 10 years broken up or continuously, one could ultimately say that you still *lived* only 3 score and 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

There are many variables that affect longevity. We don't know if periods of metabolic stasis are one of them.

It certainly sounds plausible that long periods of hibernation could increase the lifespan of an animal relative to one that doesn't spend time in stasis.

As soon as you bring magic into the equation all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

IF stasis in your case means a creature's metaboly is literally stopped. By this I mean that all cellular or whatever reactions that sustain the creature are put on hold and literally stop, then in a biological sense such a creature does not age at all, so long it remains in this stasis state.

You can increase the life span of creatures with this kind of stasis indefinitely, as it only ages when it is out of stasis state.

Naturally I don't take into account external causes that may kill or age the creature in stasis, as you only asked whether the stasis effect will increase the lifespan of a being. The answer to that is *yes*.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!